# Ordering by 2 columns to get a distinct

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to compare dimensions from 2 different tables-`box` and `container`. I join on the order Id and the width, height and weight. I need both Primary Ids to be in the final query, but cannot join on them, since they are not related. I want to get the distinct dimensions for each ID, but when I add both IDs in, the records double because of the ordering.

```
 CREATE TABLE #box
(OrderId int
,BoxId int
,width int
,height int
,weight int)

INSERT INTO #box(OrderId,BoxId, width, height, weight)
VALUES
(655543, 54386, 30 , 12 , 6 ),
(655543, 54386, 30 , 12 , 6 ),
(655543, 27421, 30 , 12 , 6 ),
(655543, 27421, 30 , 12 , 6 )

CREATE TABLE #container
(OrderId int
,ContainerId int
,width int
,height int
,weight int)

INSERT INTO #container(OrderId,ContainerId, width, height, weight)
VALUES
(655543, 12353, 30 , 12 , 6 ),
(655543, 12353, 30 , 12 , 6 ),
(655543, 65437, 30 , 12 , 6 ),
(655543, 65437, 30 , 12 , 6 )

SELECT DISTINCT b.OrderId,c.ContainerId,b.BoxId,b.width,b.height,b.weight
FROM #box b
JOIN #container c ON c.OrderId =b.OrderId
AND c.width=b.width AND c.height=b.height
AND c.weight=b.weight
ORDER BY c.ContainerId,b.BoxId
```

If both box Id and Container Id would be ordered at the same time, there would be 2 distinct records, and not 4.

How can I have ContainerId and BoxID ordered in a way that the results of this query returns 2 records (with all columns included)?

I cannot either do two sub queries with ROW_NUMBER since the ROW_NUMBER won't always match

Comment: there won't be a straight way since you are displaying `boxid`

Comment: You've got 2 boxIds and 2 containerIds - that's four combinations thus, four rows. If there are always 2 of each you could group by and min() and max() them, otherwise you're going to have to tolerate more rows. What's meant to happen when there are three of each? Or two of one, four of the other?